# How to JBOSS deploy ESAPI property files directory configurtion

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, owasp, esapi

We'd like to configure ESAPI property files directory, in JBOSS WildFly
(What usually done by VM argument: -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="/path/to/.esapi")
but prefer to do so in OTHER way, to suppurt diffrent property configuration for diffrent projects

does someone know how to do so?

Thaks!

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to have a single esapi jarFile that can be independently loaded on the same server with different configurations?

Answer (score 0):

There's really only two methods for loading these files, neither of them care about the application server you use.  The first method, as you suggested is to supply the path via JVM properties.

The second method is via the classpath.  I've never worked in JBOSS, but in Weblogic there's a config menu where you can place files on the classpath directly.  In your case, it sounds like you want a different properties file for multiple applications?  A JVM property or a similar classpath edit to weblogic would be the only choices.

The final classpath method, which I'm only including to be complete, is to compile your own copy of the library with your properties files in src/main/resources.   Or--really hacky--crack open the jar file and dump them in by hand.   The benefit of the "compile yourself" approach is that you'll have all the unpublished bugfixes, so if another CWE gets assigned to it you don't have to wait for the official release.